# How to typecheck polymorphic function in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have trouble with polymorphic functions in Flow.

```
type A = { id: string };
type B = { id: number };

function takeId(x) {
  return x.id;
}

const a: A = { id: 'akn2' };
const b: B = { id: 14 }; 

(takeId(a) : string);
// Error 
(takeId(b) : number);
// Error
```

I understand that flow engine will type polymorphic function accordingly to context, and where they have been called.

In this case, I reckon that `takeId` will have the following type : `(A|B) => (string | number)`. That's probably why I can't cast the return to its real type.

Furthermore, the code still doesn't typecheck if I cast `takeId` with the following type `(A => string) | (B => number)`;

How to make the return of polymorphic function typecheck with Flow, without loosing security (no `any` for instance) ?

If not possible, what would be an idomatic way of achieving the same result (factorizing `takeId`) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your example is that Flow can't refine the return type because it doesn't know how the output type correlates to input type.
You can do something like that to express this relationship:

```
type A = { id: string };
type B = { id: number };
type Entity<I> = { id: I };

function takeId<T>(x: Entity<T>): T {
  return x.id;
}

const a: A = { id: 'akn2' };
const b: B = { id: 14 }; 

(takeId(a) : string);
// OK
(takeId(b) : number);
// OK
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been really helpful :)